# Windows 8 C# Store app - Link to store and reviews

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

We are about to submit a game for Windows 8 with two versions:

- An ad-supported free version with 3 levels
- The full game

So on the ad-supported version, we need a button to link to the store for the full version.

In both versions, we also would like to place a button to link to the store to review each app.

How are these two scenarios handled in Windows 8?

Comment: Why don't you just do one version with a trial?

Comment: We didn't want to show/hide ads (and levels) based on the trial (this is also a cross-platform game, so two versions is easier across the board).  However that isn't the point of the question, need to link to reviews in either case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to the lovely folks who created Physamajig not only working this out, but also sharing the information on their blog!  Here's how you can link directly to your Review page:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=MY_PACKAGE_FAMILY_NAME"));
```

Replacing MY_PACKAGE_FAMILY_NAME with the one from your package manifest.

See full details: http://andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/227/Default.aspx

Comment: And you can get Package Family Name (PFN) programatically: `Package.Current.Id.FamilyName`

Comment: this worked for me only for Windows Store, not for Windows Phone

Answer (score 6):

```
var storeURI = new Uri("ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=<Your package family name from the manifest>");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(storeURI);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to go direct to the reviews tab.  The following URL gives the details of what you can do, though -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974767.aspx

Comment: Fruit Ninja does it.  See their settings charm.

Comment: I don't know how the do it, in that case.  Sorry.

Comment: Note that the URI need not be hard-coded. The URI can be accessed via the Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LinkUri property.

Comment: Good note Nathan. I wondered where I could get that from, but was not in a position to do the research fully. Thanks.

Comment: It's not linking the current app, but a different app.  So I don't think we can use `LinkUri`.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Fruit Ninja only seems to have the default Rate & Review link which is automatically added to apps in the Store. you don't have to do anything special to get that.

Comment: I think the marked answer is slightly misleading from your point of view.  The automatically added links are for the current app, but you stated in these comments you want a link to another app / apps.  Worth remembering that this answer will allow you to specify which apps to link to manually.

Answer (score 3):

We asked about linking directly to the review page at an AEL today.  The link to Rate and Review in the settings charm is added automatically once your app is in the store.  No coding required.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use below code in click event:

```
MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();

marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

You will need to add

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

also.

Comment: Is this available on Windows 8? This is a Window 8 Store app question.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:-

```
private async void Rate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String pfn = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=" + pfn + ""));
    }
```

You can find detailed solution [here](http://windevlab.blogspot.com/2014/08/add-rate-and-review-button-in-windows-8.html).