# How to check in c# Windows 8 application if it has been already rated and reviewed by current user

Tags: c#, windows-8, runtime, windows-store-apps

My goal is to display message that begs current user to rate and review my freeware Windows 8 application in Windows Store. I don't want to show that message if the application has been already rated and reviewed.

So my question is:
How can I check at runtime if my Windows 8 application has been already rated and reviwed by current user?

I already know that applications, which are installed through the Windows Store, has the "Rate and review" in settings, but users rather rarely uses it when they don't have to change  application settings at all.

Comment: Not sure if possible, but you could always check, for whether you've asked the user already, by setting a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to ask you to review and rate your app if you haven't done so and provide a link to your app in the store. See sample code below.

var storeURI = new Uri("ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(storeURI);

More info on "Windows 8 C# Store app - Link to store and reviews" at  [Windows 8 C# Store app - Link to store and reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532034/windows-8-c-sharp-store-app-link-to-store-and-reviews)